# Passing a model from view back to controller to export as CSV

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, csv, razor

I am trying to make a downloadable CSV. The problem I am having is I am quite unsure how to properly pass the data from the view back over to the controller.

All of my data I want in the CSV is inside @Model.Table. Problem is I am not sure how to pass over that data properly back into my controller. Notice in my js below I try to do that using csvData = @Model.Table.ToCsv(). This horribly fails so I am unsure how to properly do this.

```
<div class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="dispoCSV">
    <i class="icon-file-alt"></i>
    Disposition Report</div>
<script>
    $("#dispoCSV").click(function () {
        var csvData = @Model.Table.ToCsv();
        $.post("Respondent/DownloadCSV", function (data) {
            csvData
            })
        });
</script>
```

When I am pass this obstacle I think I can easily firgure our how to make my DownloadCSV method turn this into a csv.

Comment: You just need a form and submit it. It looks like you're trying to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: How are you generating the table?

Comment: unfortunately this already nested in a form.

Comment: Also I am generating the table using json that is passed over into the model.table

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to convert to CSV from the view. Your controller can do that. I would try it like this:

Model:

```
public class YourModel {
    public YourDataType Table { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model YourModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "YourController", FormMethod.Post)) {
    // Put your model properties in the form so that they get passed to the controller on form submit;
    // use @Html.HiddenFor if you want to hide them from being displayed.
    // Since your table property has nested properties, you probably need a custom editor template for this.
}
```

Controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller {

    // Include an action here to display your view

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(YourModel model) {
        var csvData = model.Table.ToCsv(); // assuming you have this method already since it's in your code above
        // Do something with the data and return a view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the entire data back, You should be passing the filter criteria which can be used to generate the data. And in your Action method, Read this criteria and Produce the data and send it in CSV format back the UI.

Comment: So access the data. Display in view. Then use the click button to go back to controller access data again and put in csv. It seems to me that it would be easier to access data once?